# SQL left join table with just some rows by id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am very new to SQL and I know that this is pretty basic but I just don't find a solution. I have two tables which I want to LEFT-Join together, but the problem is that I need from one of the tables just some rows. Here is the query I have:

```
select i.recipeid
from ingredients i left join useringredients ui
on ui.ingredient = i.ingredient
group by i.recipeid
having count(*) = count(ui.ingredient);
```

Now I just want to join the whole ingredients table with the user ingredients tables part where the user_id = 1. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

### An Example:

> In the ingredients table I have:

[image]

> In the user ingredients table I have:

[image]

Now I want for the user id 0 to return recipe 14 because he has "Mehl" and "Butter" but for user id 1 I want to return nothing because he just has "Butter" but no "Mehl".

Comment: use where  .. user_id = 1

Comment: `having count(*) = count(ui.ingredient)` - it is better to remove it but add `WHERE ui.ingredient IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @scaisEdge that's what I already tried but it either gives me an error or all recipes.

Comment: @Akina that's giving a syntax error

Comment: If you don't want any aggregation then it's just a simple INNER join: `select i.* from ingredients i inner join useringredients ui on ui.ingredient = i.ingredient where ui.user_id = 1;`

Comment: *that's giving a syntax error* Have you inserted WHERE between ON and GROUP BY clauses? or instead of HAVING? PS. When you receive some error then you must provife complete unchanged text of error message.

Comment: @Akina I used it instead and the error is:Ausführung wurde mit Fehlern beendet.
Ergebnis: near "WHERE": syntax error

Comment: WHERE clause must be immediately before GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Akina it always throws the same error

Comment: You do wrongly something - the final query is synthactically correct. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e92c3b1bfd70196d14dd035cdf575ae)

Comment: @Akina Thanks I found my issue but there comes the problem up where it gives me all different recipes which contain either "Mehl" or "Butter"

Comment: Replace your pictures with according CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO and show desired output for this data. Or create fiddle with your structures/data and provide a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the condition `ui.id = ?` in the `ON` clause:

```
select i.recipeid
from ingredients i left join useringredients ui
on ui.ingredient = i.ingredient and ui.id = 0
group by i.recipeid
having count(*) = count(ui.ingredient);
```